# How can I write this type of "V" in latex in the image below

Tags: equations, mathtools, vector, write, mathspec

How can I write this type of "V" in latex

[image: How can I write this type of "V" in latex]

Comment: Try https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html and/or give more context

Comment: I attached an image to it. Kindly, check. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Answer (score 4):

The image is not enough clear, but my guess is that you are looking for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\huge$\mathbb{V}$
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]